# Booting into TWRP fails

Tags: fastboot, motorola-moto-g, twrp

I have a Motorola Moto G 2014 XT1068 (Titan) with an unlocked bootloader. I am running the stock ROM, recovery, kernel, etc. for my device and my device is not rooted. After I download the latest TWRP image for my device from [here](https://dl.twrp.me/titan/twrp-2.8.6.0-titan.img.html), I run the command `fastboot boot twrp-2.8.6.0-titan.img.html` whilst in fastboot mode. The output on the PC looks fine: `downloading boot.img... OKAY [0.358s] booting... OKAY [0.229s] finished. total time: 0.587s`. The device then displays the Motorola boot logo briefly before a blank screen appeared. The device then repeatedly flashes up the logo (for even less time than it did immediately after the command) before displaying a blank screen for around 5 seconds. This goes on until I hold down the power button to boot back into Android, which works fine. I have tried these steps twice now and both times they have failed. How can I successfully boot into TWRP recovery? Please note that I do not want to flash the recovery, but boot it. I am able to run the same command for the appropriate TWRP image on my Nexus 7 and it works fine.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use the command `fastboot boot twrp-2.8.6.0-titan.img`. Are you sure you downloaded the `.img` file (8.5 MB) and not an `.HTML` file?

Comment: This is the command I am running and I have downloaded the correct IMG file.

Comment: @user1871 I just noticed when looking back at this after so long that the file extension in my post did indeed end in .html. I suspect this was the issue.

Comment: @Firelord I just noticed when looking back at this after so long that the file extension in my post did indeed end in .html. I suspect this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error so after a lot of research I referenced this site: http://androidforums.com/threads/recovery-unofficial-cwm-6-0-5-0-peregrine.859010/

Before you flash recovery you need to transfer the file to the SD card. After I did that I ran the below:

```
C:\adb>fastboot flash recovery CWM-6.0.5.0-peregrine.img
```

I then booted into recovery mode and it worked.  You need a different build because I have an XT1040 and you have an XT1068 but the same general principles should apply.

Comment: *please note that I do not want to flash the recovery, but boot it.* -- Your answer is against it.

Comment: Yes, I am able to run `fastboot flash` but not `fastboot boot`.

Comment: Why do you transfer the file to the SD card? Your command is correct, but Fastboot will push the file from the PC directly to the phone, you don't transfer it before hand.